# I can't click checkboxes in selenium python(Getting NoSuchElementException error)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to go to startup India(Website hosted by the government for startups) and connect with startup page there are some checkboxes which are used for finding relevant startup company's you want to find and I want to click some checkboxes in selenium webdriver python but even though my Xpath is correct I always get a NoSuchElement exception and the funny part here is when I only try for one checkbox it works perfectly and when I try for the second checkbox I always get a NoSuchElementException error.

This is the code I tried :

```
# Importing the required packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time


try:
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(cwd + "/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.startupindia.gov.in/content/sih/en/search.html?roles=Startup&page=0")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='mCSB_container']//label)[2]").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()[normalize-space()='Accounting']]").click()
finally:
    print("It works!")
```

I tried things like time.sleep(5) and all but none of them worked please help me to find the solution for my problem.

Comment: no div tag exist with class "mCSB_container" in the given page.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: div[@class='mCSB_container'] does'nt exist. check once again

Comment: div[@class='mCSB_container'] does exist I just checked it.